# MediaPlayer not initializing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

```
package com.m.omg;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;     
import android.content.Context;  
import android.content.Intent;   
import android.media.MediaPlayer;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;  
import android.widget.Toast; 

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  
{   
MediaPlayer mp =new MediaPlayer();  
@Override  
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)   
{  

    String mymsg = null;
    String num = null;

    //get the SMS message passed in
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;            
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //retrieving the received SMS
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            num = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            mymsg = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, "from" + num + ":" + mymsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //making decision, depending on the number & message body
        if (num.equalsIgnoreCase("some# :) ")){
            abortBroadcast();
            if (mymsg.equalsIgnoreCase("start")){

        mp.create(context, R.raw.music);
        mp.start();

            }
        } 
        mp.release();
    }    
}
```

}

**media player not initialized when the condition is matched... the app works normally, when I receive the SMS, the Toast is displayed but media player is not triggered, I get this warning in eclipse "The static method create(Context, int) from the type MediaPlayer should be accessed in a static way" which I ignored it :D **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
mp=MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.music);
```

instead of

```
mp.create(context, R.raw.music);
```

for initializing `mp` instance of MediaPlayer

Comment: Thanks alot dude,I appreciate it,but I've tried it again and there was no music playing after receiving the SMS,I noticed that am releasing the MediaPlayer before it can even play the music, I removed the mp.release();,and added mp.reset(); before mp=MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.music);  ... And it actually worked greatly, but I beleive that mp.release(); is necessary,isn't it? so, where should I add mp.release();??<<please note that my music file playing duration is as short as 3 sec>>..thanks again :)